# Scalable distributed file system for blobs like images and other documents

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hbase

Cassandra & HBase both do not efficiently support storage of blobs like images. Storing directly on HDFS stresses the Namenode. [Facebook's Haystack](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919) is not open source. So is [Lustre](http://www.lustre.org/) a good choice for distributed blob storage? What are other suggestions?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961191/scalable-image-storage